# Hero animation start delayed

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to implement a transition between two controllers with [Hero](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) inside a navigation controller.
I have this method to handle a pan gesture:

```
@objc func pannedCell(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let animatedView = gesture.view as? HotelListingCollectionViewCell else {
        return
    }
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: nil)
    let screenHeight = self.rootView.bounds.height
    let progress = ((-1 * translation.y) / screenHeight) * 2
    print(progress)

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        self.initialViewPostion = animatedView.center
        Hero.shared.defaultAnimation = .fade
            let vc = ListingSearchViewController()
            vc.viewModel.hotels.value = self.viewModel.hotels.value
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    case .changed:
        Hero.shared.update(progress)
        let pos = CGPoint(
                x: animatedView.center.x + translation.x,
                y: self.rootView.hotelResultsCollectionView.center.y + translation.y
        )
            Hero.shared.apply(modifiers: [
                .position(pos),
                .useGlobalCoordinateSpace,
                .useOptimizedSnapshot
            ], to: animatedView)
    default:
        if progress > 0.8 {
                Hero.shared.finish()
        } else {
                Hero.shared.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is the pushViewController method takes ~ 1 second to execute so when I start dragging my view, it moves under my finger approx. 1 second after I started moving the finger on the screen.

I am doing it wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found something !

The issue seems to be related to operation I did in .began case of the gesture handler.

I moved the instantiation of the new view controller out of this call back to avoid overloading the UI thread during the animation and everything seems to work as expected.